# how can i relate question and answer set to one particular article?

Tags: django

i created one article on stack,at the end of this article provide link to next page which have set of ques-ans related to stack but when i create second article on linked list then on the next page it still display ques-ans for the stack.how can i differentiate ques-ans to one particular article?

one post have multiple ques-ans so i use foreign key concept but still i not get a result which i want.

in **blog/models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    qustion_set = models.ForeignKey(Practice,default = "",editable = False,on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

in **practice.models.py**

```
class Practice(models.Model):

    question = models.TextField()
    answer = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('practice-create')
```

in post_practice.html:-

```
{% for practice in practices %}
    <b>Que: {{ practice.question }}</b><br>
    <b>Ans:</b> {{ practice.answer }}<br>
    <br>
{% endfor %}
<div class="">
    <p>If you want to share your experience and want to upload questions 
       from your side then <a href="{% url 'practice-create' 
       %}">upload</a> 
       on this page.
    </p>
</div>
<div class="">
    <p>To test and want to hone your skills then click on <a href="{% url 
       'practice-online' %}">IDE.</a></p>
</div>
```

in view.py:-

def post_practice(request, **kwargs):

```
context = {
    'practices':Practice.objects.all()
}
return render(request, 'practice/post_practice.html', context)
```

class PracticeCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

```
model = Practice
fields = ['question', 'answer']

def form_valid(self, form):
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

@login_required

def practice_ide(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SnippetForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
else:

    form = SnippetForm()
return render(request, "practice/practice_online.html", {
    "form": form,
    "snippets": Snippet.objects.all()
})
```

it gives operational error like no such column: blog_post.qustion_set_id

Comment: It could be better if you can include related templates and views in the question.

Comment: You likely forgot to run migrations (or the migrations raised an error)